# Обобщающее слово в предложении

Tags: синтаксис

Есть ли в этом предложение обобщающее слово:

**Родному близкому человеку — матери.**

Comment: Здесь первоначально стоял дефис, но так писать нельзя, нет такого понятия "человек-мать". Я исправил.

Answer (score 4):

**Родному близкому человеку —  (а именно) матери.**

Здесь нет обобщающего слова, обособляется с помощью тире приложение пояснительного характера.

И это не предложение, а распространенное назывное словосочетание.